# Porting native C++ server with XML commands and huge in-memory project data to webservice. How todo and which Framework?

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, master-data-management

we have an existing C++ (STL, boost, Qt4) server application which communicates by xml commands over tcp sockets with the clients. The interface is proprietary, but not so far from SOAP, but with one exception. We have large set of master- and (calculated) project data, which is initialize and calculated at server startup (and updated later on). Building and calculating this data on every service request is much to expensive.

Now we want to port some (in future all) commands to web-services. We found/evaluating the following C++ frameworks:

- [Staff](http://code.google.com/p/staff/)
- [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)
- [WSO2](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/cpp/)
- [Roguewave Hydra](http://www.roguewave.com/products/hydraexpress/overview/features.aspx)

Now my questions ;-)

1. How is the standard way to build a web-service which have access to permanent in-memory project data, which be initialized at server startup (not web-service request)? Are the any resources on the net?
2. Can above be solved with gSOAP own HTTP Get plugins?
3. Have i forgot a **recommendable** C++/web-service framework?

Thanks in advance Lars

Answer (score -1):

1. memcached or a real database of some sort. Depends really on how much concurrent usage there is and will the dataset be modifiable by multiple clients.

Others, no idea..

Comment: Thanx for reply. We use at a moment a memcached procedure. The base Question is which framework supports a method to init the memcached data at startup of web-server? or what else.